# I need to restore my data from a non time machine manual backup

Tags: macos, restore

My machine crashed and I made a manual backup to an external drive...how can i restore all my user data including mailbox data...am I screwed. I did not use time machine backup to back up my data just did a straight copy of the disk drive to a folder on my external drive

Answer (score 1):

You can get your data back.  It might be fairly easy with migration assistant.

There is probably some way of coping the data back & getting your mac to boot.

What OS X are you running?

What you did was drag the Macintosh harddrive Icon on the desktop to the external folder?

You may want to post your question here:
https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_os/mac_os_x_technologies

Or the discussion for your OS X version.

---

Whatever the case, you will be able to recover your data.  You may have to copy over it folder by folder.

I believe that you can use migration assistant to move everything back.
Macintosh-HD -> Applications -> Utilities -> Migration Assistant

In that case, re-install the OS. Then run Migration Assistant

---

What is the state of your machine?  Is it working?  How did it crash?